# validateMenuItem or menuWillOpen not called for NSMenu

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

My Mac app has an NSMenu whose delegate functions `validateMenuItem` and `menuWillOpen` are never called. So far none of the solutions online have helped.

It seems like I'm doing everything right:

- The menu item's selectors are in the same class.
- The class managing it inherits from NSMenuDelegate

I suppose the best way to describe my problem is to post the relevant code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Cocoa

class UIManager: NSObject, NSMenuDelegate {    
    var statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: -2)
    var statusBarMenu = NSMenu()
    var titleMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    var descriptionMenuItem = NSMenuItem()

    // ...

    override init() {            
        super.init()

        createStatusBarMenu()
    }

    // ...

    func createStatusBarMenu() {
        // Status bar icon
        guard let icon = NSImage(named: "iconFrame44")
            else { NSLog("Error setting status bar icon image."); return }
        icon.isTemplate = true
        statusBarItem.image = icon

        // Create Submenu items
        let viewOnRedditMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "View on Reddit...", action: #selector(viewOnRedditAction), keyEquivalent: "")
        let saveThisImageMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Save This Image...", action: #selector(saveThisImageAction), keyEquivalent: "")

        // Add to title submenu
        let titleSubmenu = NSMenu(title: "")
        titleSubmenu.addItem(descriptionMenuItem)
        titleSubmenu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        titleSubmenu.addItem(viewOnRedditMenuItem)
        titleSubmenu.addItem(saveThisImageMenuItem)

        // Create main menu items
        titleMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "No Wallpaperer Image", action: nil, keyEquivalent: "")
        titleMenuItem.submenu = titleSubmenu
        getNewWallpaperMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Update Now", action: #selector(getNewWallpaperAction), keyEquivalent: "")
        let preferencesMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Preferences...", action: #selector(preferencesAction), keyEquivalent: "")
        let quitMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Quit Wallpaperer", action: #selector(quitAction), keyEquivalent: "")

        // Add to main menu
        let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "")
        statusBarMenu.addItem(titleMenuItem)
        statusBarMenu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        statusBarMenu.addItem(getNewWallpaperMenuItem)
        statusBarMenu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
        statusBarMenu.addItem(preferencesMenuItem)
        statusBarMenu.addItem(quitMenuItem)

        statusBarItem.menu = statusBarMenu
    }

    // ...

    // Called whenever the menu is about to show. we use it to change the menu based on the current UI mode (offline/updating/etc)
    override func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        NSLog("Validating menu item")
        if (menuItem == getNewWallpaperMenuItem) {
            if wallpaperUpdater!.state == .Busy {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.getNewWallpaperMenuItem.title = "Updating Wallpaper..."
                }
                return false
            } else if wallpaperUpdater!.state == .Offline {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.getNewWallpaperMenuItem.title = "No Internet Connection"
                }
                return false
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.preferencesViewController.updateNowButton.title = "Update Now"
                }
                return true
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    // Whenever the menu is opened, we update the submitted time
    func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
        NSLog("Menu will open")
        if !noWallpapererImageMode {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.descriptionMenuItem.title = "Submitted \(self.dateSimplifier(self.updateManager!.thisPost.attributes.created_utc as Date)) by \(self.updateManager!.thisPost.attributes.author) to /r/\(self.updateManager!.thisPost.attributes.subreddit)"
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    // MARK: User-initiated actions

    func viewOnRedditAction() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.reddit.com\(updateManager!.thisPost.permalink)")
            else { NSLog("Could not convert post permalink to URL."); return }
        NSWorkspace.shared().open(url)
    }

    // Present a save panel to let the user save the current wallpaper
    func saveThisImageAction() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
            savePanel.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

            savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = self.updateManager!.thisPost.id + ".png"
            let result = savePanel.runModal()

            if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
                let exportedFileURL = savePanel.url!
                guard let lastImagePath = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastImagePath")
                    else { NSLog("Error getting last post ID from persistent storage."); return }
                let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: lastImagePath))
                if (try? imageData.write(to: exportedFileURL, options: [.atomic])) == nil {
                    NSLog("Error saving image to user-specified folder.")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getNewWallpaperAction() {
        updateManager!.refreshAndReschedule(userInitiated: true)
    }

    func preferencesAction() {
        preferencesWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
    }

    func quitAction() {
        NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to set the menu's delegate anywhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the menuWillOpen problem. This doesn't fix my problem with validateMenuItem though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`menuWillOpen:` belongs to the `NSMenuDelegate` protocol; for it to be called the menu in question needs a delegate:

```
let statusBarMenu = NSMenu(title: "")
statusBarMenu.delegate = self
```

---

`validateMenuItem:` belongs to the `NSMenuValidation` informal protocol; for it to be called the relevant menu *items* must have a `target`. The following passage is taken from Apple's [Application Menu and Pop-up List Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html) documentation:

> When you use automatic menu enabling, NSMenu updates the status of every menu item whenever a user event occurs. To update the status of a menu item, NSMenu first determines the target of the item and then determines whether the target implements validateMenuItem: or validateUserInterfaceItem: (in that order).

```
let myMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
myMenuItem.target = self
myMenuItem.action = #selector(doSomething)
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I added the line `statusBarMenu.delegate = self` and added `myMenuItem.target = self` after the initialization of each menu item that had an action.

Comment: if the menuitem does not have an action, does validatemenuitem not get called?

Comment: Declare support for NSMenuItemValidation, in your target (ie: class MyTargetClass: NSObject, NSMenuItemValidation ...). A lot of issues stem from the fact that swift is fairly different than obj-c ... it keeps biting me

Answer (score 4):

The above (accepted) answer states that a target *must* be set, is a bit misleading. It is not required to set a target. You can (for example) also make the first responder, without explicitly setting a  target.

Details can be found in the appel documentation, which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html

There is one tricky part though when using swift:

if validateMenuItem does not get called, then make sure your class not only declares conformance to NSMenuDelegate, but *also* to NSMenuItemValidation.

```
class SomeClass: NSMenuDelegate, NSMenuItemValidation {
...
func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
   return true // or whatever, on whichever condition
}
}
```

Comment: The most pathetic thing is why do I have to validate a menu item that is already enabled on storyboard and that I always wanted to be enabled? This should only be required if I wanted to disable some menu item. Apple and their psychotic manias.

Comment: Well, validateMenuItem() is super handy when you want to rename a menu item based on the context of a first responder.

Comment: Another bit to why `validateMenuItem` may not be called is make sure that it is bound to correct IBAction method.