# validateMenuItem not called for every menu item

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, menu

I have main menu that has several menu items (File, Edit, View, Window - and more). All menu items have their action set to an operation in `FirstResponder`.

The application has a single window and that window is of the type `MyWindow` that inherits from `NSWindow` (see below).

Note that `NSWindow` implements `NSMenuValidation` and hence it is flagged as an error when `MyWindow` would declare conformance to `NSMenuValidation`.

I have overriden the function `validateMenuItem` as follows:

```
class MyWindow: NSWindow, NSMenuDelegate {

    ...

    override func validateMenuItem(_ item: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        Log.atDebug?.log("\(item.title)")
        ....
    }
}
```

When I run the application the `validateMenuItem` function is called for the `File` and the `Window` menu items but not for the `Edit` and `View` items.

Note: Log is an instance of a logging framework (SwifterLog).

The actions for all menu items are called correctly. (Also for the menu items for which the `validateMenuItem` is not called)

It is not difficult for me to work around this problem (the function `menuNeedsUpdate` is called for all menu's and can be used for this), but I would like to know why this behaviour occurs.

Comment: Is a text field, text view or other object validating the edit menu items?

Comment: I'm shocked it works at all. The validation/enabling of the top-level submenu items is probably tied to some voodoo in the internal workings of AppKit and the normal validation for those top-level menu items is getting short-circuited.

Comment: @Willeke, it is tied to the MyWindow object as shown in the code using Firstresponder

Comment: @JamesBucanek: this used to work fine in earlier versions of macOS (well, OSX actually)

Comment: If you feel this is a documented feature of the top-level menu items that no longer works correctly, I would suggest filing a bug report. But my feeling is that this is a side-effect of private framework code and, as such, is a moving target. The bug report feedback should get you Apple's opinion on the matter—which has a lot more weight than mine. ;)

Comment: I suspect that this is indeed a bug and has been introduced by the default compliance to the NSMenuValidation protocol of NSWindow.

Comment: This is not a bug of NSWindow having any conformance. The issue is who implements the method that the action is tied to. If for example, you implement `- (void)performFindPanelAction:(id)sender { }` in your class, you'll find that your `-validateMenuItems:` call will now be triggered for those menu items that have that selector.

Comment: @Lucas: No not really. MyWindow implements all action methods, but still validateMenuItem is not called for all of them. It does not matter if I use FirstResponder as an intermediate or directly tie the action to MyWindow itself. The behaviour does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer can be found here:
[validateMenuItem or menuWillOpen not called for NSMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461449/validatemenuitem-or-menuwillopen-not-called-for-nsmenu)

> `validateMenuItem:` belongs to the `NSMenuValidation` informal protocol;
>   for it to be called the relevant menu items **must have a target**.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but to anyone interested in a work-around:

```
@objc func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu) {

    Log.atDebug?.log("\(menu.title)")

    ...    // do other stuff    

    menu.items.forEach( { $0.isEnabled = validateMenuItem($0) } )
}
```

You must als set the delegate of each menu that must be handled to the MyWindow object (in this example). In my example, the menu of the menu item `View` must have its delegate set to `MyWindow`.